# how to identify php imap client to gmail?

Tags: php, gmail, imap, php-imap

I want to identify my php imap client to gmail so user can check which imap is currently  using the gmail.

The details who is using the gmail inbox right now can be check by click on details
[gmail activity details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDgDu.png)

when check email by thunderbird using imap connection. thunderbird identify itself like this
[thunderbird imap details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfoZE.png)

but when I try to get email gmail cannot recognize who is currently getting the emails

[php imap details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h8FG.png)

can you tell which headers I need to pass in order to tell gmail that my client is reading the emails

Comment: I imagine it's using the IMAP 'ID' command.  You'll have to check the documentation to see if php_imap supports it.

Comment: A quick look at the API looks like this isn't imeplemented, so you're out of luck.

Comment: @Max ok thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anwser by the [@max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) its looks like PHP imap implemantion doesn't allow to set ID of the imap client

further info available here [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2971)

> The ID extension to the Internet Message Access Protocol - Version
> 4rev1 (IMAP4rev1) protocol allows the server and client to exchange
> **identification information** on their implementation in order to make
> bug reports and usage statistics more complete.